# numpy.array() exceptions thrown (sorry for the initially horrible title)

Tags: python, numpy, duck-typing

I am learning Python and numpy, and am new to the idea of duck typing.  I'm writing functions into which something/someone should pass a numpy array.  Trying to embrace duck typing, I'm writing my code to use `numpy.array` with the `copy=` and `ndmin=` options to convert array_likes or 1d/0d arrays into the shape I need.  Specifically, I use the `ndmin=` option in cases where I can accept either a `(p,p)` array or a scalar; the scalar can be coded as an `int`, `(1,)` array, `(1,1)` array, `[1]` list, etc...

So to take care of this, I'm using something like `S = numpy.array(S,copy=False,ndmin=2)` to get an array (if possible) with the right `ndim`, then test for the shape as I need.  I know I should embed this in a Try-Except block, but can't find any documentation about what kind of exception `numpy.array()` is likely to throw.  Thus I currently just have this:

```
# duck covariance matrix into a 2d matrix
try:
    S = numpy.array(S, ndmin = 2, copy=False)
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

What specific exception(s) should I try to catch here?  Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure you are clear about this: 1. `ndmin` is the minimum dimension not the exact dimension, the result might be 3D 2. why at all a `try: ...` since you propagate the exception anyways? (btw. its a ValueError)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm forcing ndmin to be at least 2, then later check S.ndim=2 and raise my own ValueError if not.

Comment: Re. raising the error, I would raise the error with my own message appended, something like `raise ValueError("Input should be an array of size (p,p): %s"%EntComp.__doc__)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Document your function as accepting an array_like object and leave handling of exceptions to a caller.

`numpy.array()` is very permissive function it will convert to an array almost anything.

Comment: Thanks @J.F. If numpy is really that permissive, I'll just keep the generic raise.

Comment: @Dr.Drew: to be clear: I've suggested to remove completely the try/except block around the numpy.array().

Comment: Ah, ok. Really?  You wouldn't even catch and reraise the same error?

Comment: @Dr.Drew: yes. It is useless here. btw, the correct way to reraise an exception in the `except` block is to use bare `raise` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`np.asarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) to convert inputs into arrays instead. It's guaranteed not to copy anything if the input is already a Numpy array. If you expect to receive `array` subclasses, use `np.asanyarray`.

Note that a lot of Numpy interfaces don't care if the input is 1- or 2-dimensional -- for example, `np.dot` works with both 1- and 2-dimensional input. It's probably best to leave it that way -- that way, things like scalar multiplication *just work*.

Comment: `np.asarray` is nice, but its actually just `np.array` with `copy=False`.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification! I (clearly) did not know that. In terms of which one is used for what purpose, though, it seems typical to use `asarray` on input parameters rather than `array(..., copy=False)`. (I guess this is because `asarray` is slightly simpler).

Comment: @mneonneo: I understand that numpy _often_ doesn't care (but try numpy.trace() or numpy.linalg.det() on someting that is not a 2d array.  For some of _my_ uses, I have to care.  I prefer to use `array(...,copy=False)` as it is the same as `asarray()`, it adds implicit documentation to my code, and shows I know exactly what I'm expecting to occur.

Comment: @Dr.Drew if you really want to only allow arrays and subclasses of it, I would first check explicitely with `isinstance(array, np.ndarray)`.

Comment: @seberg: I started doing that, but I want to use Python how intended and embrace the duck.  More importantly, I'm ok with array_like inputs as long as it makes sense.